# Spring Integration - Request-Reply Implementation

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am new to Spring Integration and new to Stack Overflow. I am looking for some help in understanding Spring Integration as it relates to a request-reply pattern. From reading on the web, I am thinking that I should be using a Service Activator to enable this type of use case.

I am using JMS to facilitate the sending and receiving of XML based messages. Our underlining implementation is IBM Websphere MQ.

I am also using Spring Boot (version 1.3.6.RELEASE) and attempting to use a pure annotation based configuration approach (if that is possible). I have searched the web and see some example but nothing that so far I can see that helps me understand how it all fits together. The Spring Integration documentation is excellent but I am still struggling with how all the pieces fit together. I apologize in advance if there is something out there that I missed. I treat posting here as a last alternative.

Here is what I have for my configuration:

```
package com.daluga.spring.integration.configuration

import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;

//import com.ibm.msg.client.services.Trace;

@Configuration
public class MQConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${host-name}")
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${channel}")
    private String channel;

    @Value("${time-to-live}")
    private int timeToLive;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MQConnectionFactory")
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean(name = "jmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate provideJmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true); 
        jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);     
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name = "MQConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory ccf  = new CachingConnectionFactory();

        //Trace.setOn();

        try {
            MQConnectionFactory mqcf = new MQConnectionFactory();
            mqcf.setHostName(hostName);
            mqcf.setPort(port);
            mqcf.setChannel(channel);
            mqcf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            ccf.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqcf);
            ccf.setSessionCacheSize(2);   
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return ccf;
    }

    @Bean(name = "requestQueue")
    public Destination createRequestQueue() {

        Destination queue = null;

        try {
            queue = new MQQueue("REQUEST.QUEUE");
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return queue;
    }

    @Bean(name = "replyQueue")
    public Destination createReplyQueue() {

        Destination queue = null;

        try {
            queue = new MQQueue("REPLY.QUEUE");
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return queue;
    }

    @Bean(name = "requestChannel")
    public QueueChannel createRequestChannel() {

        QueueChannel channel = new QueueChannel();

        return channel;
    }

    @Bean(name = "replyChannel")
    public QueueChannel createReplyChannel() {

        QueueChannel channel = new QueueChannel();

        return channel;
    }

}
```

And here is my Service class:

```
package com.daluga.spring.integration.service

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class MyRequestReplyService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRequestReplyService.class);

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "replyChannel")
    public void sendAndReceive(String requestPayload) {
        // How to get replyPayload
    }

}
```

So, at this point, I am not quite sure how to glue all this together to make this work. I don't understand how to glue together my request and reply queues to the service activator to make this all work.

The service I am calling (JMS/Webshere MQ based) is using the typical message and correlation id so that I can properly tied the request to the corresponding response.

Can anyone provide me any guidance on how to get this to work? Please let me know what additional information I can provide to make this clear.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gateways provide request/reply semantics.

Instead of using a JmsTemplate directly, you should be using [Spring Integration's built-in JMS Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html).

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requestChannel")
public MessageHandler jmsOutGateway() {
    JmsOutboundGateway outGateway = new JmsOutboundGateway();
    // set properties
    outGateway.setOutputChannel(replyChannel());
    return outGateway;
}
```

If you want to roll your own, change the service activator method the return a reply type and use one of the template `sendAndReceive()` or `convertSendAndReceive()` methods.

The [sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jms) uses XML configuration but should provide some additional guidance.

Comment: Thanks, Gary! That has helped. I took a step back and decided to use xml based configuration. I have the inbound and outbound gateways configured and can see that Message Consumer gets created on my reply queue. There are no errors in the startup. I am able to put a message to the reply queue (using an JMS utility) and see it get picked up. But what I don't understand quite yet is how to initiate the call to the request queue via the Service Activator. I created a class and annotated it with MessageEndpoint and a method on that class with ServiceActivator. I then call it via main method.

Comment: Change `requestChannel()` to a `DirectChannel` and send a `Message<?>` to it - either directly, or via a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway). We generally recommend the latter rather than user code interacting with messaging infrastructure directly. Take a look at the sample apps for examples.

Comment: Gary, thanks for your guidance!. I was able to get it all wired up and working. Once you kind of understand what's going on, it's pretty darn easy to wire one of these up. Take care, Dan.